# pygame image display overflow? (rpi photo booth)

Tags: python, image, raspberry-pi, camera, gpio

**The setup:** Hello, I've built a photobooth powered by a Raspberry Pi (Model 2 B if it matters). The gist is that the rpi camera shows a live image on screen so the users can get set up. When they push the big green button it counts down and then takes two photos. One of the photos is taken through a tether to my DSLR. This is the quality photo that I end up actually using. The other photo is taken with the rpi camera. It's played back on the screen for a few seconds so that the user can see how it turned out.

**The issue:** after approximately 100 shots (~100 MB of images) it stops playing back the rpi image on the screen. Everything else works fine. It still takes the photo on my DSLR, and it even still records an image from the rpi camera, it just doesn't display it. I should also note that it does not throw any errors or exceptions. The SD card has plenty of free space, so that's not an issue. Also, if I exit python and open it up again it all works fine again (for the first 100 or so images).

I'll be honest, I don't know the pygame library that well... Any pointers would be appreciated. Thanks!

**The code:**

```
import time
import picamera
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import atexit
import os
import sys
import pygame

#######################
### Variables Config ##
#######################

big_button = 5
led = 26
stop_button = 4
focus = 16
shoot = 12

####################
### Other Config ###
####################

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(led,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(focus,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(shoot,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(big_button,GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(stop_button,GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(32, GPIO.OUT, initial=False)

camera = picamera.PiCamera()
camera.annotate_text_size = 70
camera.annotate_background = picamera.Color('white')
camera.annotate_foreground = picamera.Color('black')

######################
### Build a Screen ###
######################

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((pygame.display.Info().current_w, pygame.display.Info().current_h), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
black = pygame.Color(0 , 0, 0)

#################
### Functions ###
#################

def shut_it_down(channel):
    print('Exiting!')
    camera.stop_preview()
    GPIO.output(led,0)
    GPIO.cleanup()
    camera.close()
    pygame.quit()
    os._exit(0)
    #os.system("sudo halt")

def take_photo():
    now = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S")
    try:
        GPIO.output(led, 0)
        GPIO.output(focus, 1)
        camera.annotate_text = '   Get ready!   '
        print('Get ready!')
        time.sleep(3)
        camera.annotate_text = '   I will count down from 5...   '
        print('Counting down')
        time.sleep(3)
        camera.annotate_text = '   5   '
        print('5')
        time.sleep(1)
        camera.annotate_text = '   4   '
        print('4')
        time.sleep(1)
        camera.annotate_text = '   3   '
        print('3')
        time.sleep(1)
        camera.annotate_text = '   2   '
        print('2')
        time.sleep(1)
        camera.annotate_text = '   1   '
        print('1')
        time.sleep(1)
        camera.annotate_text = ''
        print('Taking photo')
        GPIO.output(focus, 0)
        screen.fill(black)
        pygame.display.update()
        camera.stop_preview()
        GPIO.output(shoot, 1)
        camera.capture('Photos/weddingshots-' + now + '.jpg')
        time.sleep(1)
        GPIO.output(shoot, 0)

    finally:
        display_photo(now)

def display_photo(date):
    try:
        print('Displaying photo')
        img = pygame.image.load('Photos/weddingshots-' + date + '.jpg').convert()
        screen.blit(img, (0,0))
        pygame.display.update()
        time.sleep(10)
        screen.fill(black)
        pygame.display.update()
        camera.start_preview()

    except:
        print('Could not find photo')
        screen.fill(black)
        pygame.display.update()
        camera.start_preview()

    finally:
        GPIO.output(led, 1)

####################
### Main Program ###
####################

GPIO.add_event_detect(stop_button, GPIO.RISING, callback=shut_it_down, bouncetime=300)

GPIO.output(led, 1)
GPIO.output(32, 0)
print('Running')
camera.start_preview()

while True:
    GPIO.wait_for_edge(big_button, GPIO.RISING)
    time.sleep(0.2)
    take_photo()
```

Comment: Don't see anything obviously wrong. Maybe you can work around the problem by quitting and re-initializing `pygame` every so many shots.

Comment: Your program won't show any exceptions it may be throwing since everything is wrapped up in try blocks. Have you tried using a general catch (`except Exception as e`) and looked for any exceptions?

Comment: @martineau, that's a good suggestion, though I'd prefer to solve the problem for real. I'll resort to that if I can't solve the problem before I have to head off to the wedding

Comment: @WyattIsrael: Durr! Good point. Tomorrow night when I have some time I'll make the suggested change and see if I can get some info from an exception. Unfortunately, it takes me pressing the button 100 times before I get any information...

Comment: Ian: I suggest that you use the [`after()`](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html) universal widget method to avoid having to press the button 100 times. Make the computer do the repetitive stuff.

Comment: @WyattIsrael: okay, I used a general catch... no exceptions thrown. The other odd thing is that the live preview comes back after taking a photo, even after the error starts happening. That means that even though it seems like something is going wrong in the try block, the camera.start_preview() is still getting executed.

Comment: I was also worried that there might be some sort of memory leak so I got it to print out memory usage after every photo was taken. Between the first and the 100th image the memory use only increased about 400 KB.

Comment: Very weird. I'll investigate further this evening. Can you post the updated exception statements? Also, I'm assuming you're using Python 2.7 - is this true?

Comment: @WyattIsrael: Yes, 2.7.3.

I replaced my exception statement with "except Exception as e:
          print (e.message, e.args)" (in code format, of course).

I also tried another experiment. I added a static (i.e. same photo each time) photo, delay, and white screen fill after displaying the photo that was just taken. I did this to see if there was an issue using blit or something. After 90+ button presses all three (photo taken, static photo, white fill) updates stopped working. So I would say pygame out and out stopped working...

Comment: @martineau: I'm getting short on time so I tried your suggestion. Unfortunately, pygame does not play well with reload(), and I've found old message board posts that confirm this.

Comment: I'm not able to test this myself at the moment so I can't solve the problem exactly. Since reload isn't working it might be worth scheduling a [cron](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=39344) job to just restart the whole application every X number of minutes. Make sure you [stop the existing python processes](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=71108) as well if you choose to take this route.